# jVectorMap active marker on page load

Tags: jvectormap

i have custom colors for regions and custom images for marker icons. Hovering, clicking on markers changes everytjing like i want but... How to make one marker, marked after loading a map, i cant find solution. I've been trying to click the marker icon with jquery, finding by element attribute, the click worked (according to the console log), but nothing changed on the map.

https://jsfiddle.net/6ss2eahr/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var markers = [
        { latLng: [54.5039433, 18.3233958], name: 'Gdynia', region: 'PL-PM' },
        { latLng: [51.7472675, 18.0070145], name: 'Kalisz', region: 'PL-WP' },
        { latLng: [50.2138079, 18.8671087], name: 'Katowice', region: 'PL-SL' },
        { latLng: [50.8541274, 20.5456014], name: 'Kielce', region: 'PL-SK' }
    ];

var last_poi;

$('#map-pl').vectorMap({
    map: 'pl_merc',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    zoomButtons: false,
    zoomOnScroll: false,
    regionsSelectable: false,
    regionsSelectableOne: true,
    markersSelectable: true,
    markersSelectableOne: true,
    markers: markers,
    markerStyle: {
        initial: {
            image: 'https://www.royalparks.org.uk/_media/images/map_icons/find-my-location-icon.png'
        },
        hover: {
            image: 'http://tiltedkilt.com/wp-content/themes/base/library/images/pin-small-icon.png',
            cursor: 'pointer'
        },
        selected: {
            image: 'http://tiltedkilt.com/wp-content/themes/base/library/images/pin-small-icon.png'
        },
        selectedHover: {
            image: 'http://tiltedkilt.com/wp-content/themes/base/library/images/pin-small-icon.png'
        }
    },
    regionStyle: {
        hover: { fill: '#fdefc9' },
        initial: { stroke: "white", "stroke-width": 1, fill: "#fcf8ed" },
        selected: { fill: "#ffcc39" }
    },
    onMarkerClick: function (event, id) {
        var mapObject = $('#map-pl').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
        mapObject.clearSelectedRegions();
        mapObject.setSelectedRegions(markers[id].region);
        last_poi = id;
    },
    onMarkerOver: function (event, id) {
        var mapObject = $('#map-pl').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
        mapObject.clearSelectedRegions();
        if (last_poi) {
            mapObject.setSelectedRegions(markers[last_poi].region);
        }
        mapObject.setSelectedRegions(markers[id].region);
    },
    onMarkerOut: function (event, id) {
        var mapObject = $('#map-pl').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
        mapObject.clearSelectedRegions();
        if (last_poi) {
            mapObject.setSelectedRegions(markers[last_poi].region);
        }
    },
    onRegionTipShow: function (e, label, code) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

All the functions `getSelectedMarkers`, `setSelectedRegions`, and so on can handle array of values, so the solution is pretty easy to dynamically select one or more Marker and the corresponding Region:

```
var mapObject = $('#map-pl').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
// select Gdynia by index
var selectedMarkers = [0],
    selectedRegions = [];
selectedMarkers.forEach(function(item) {
    selectedRegions.push(mapObject.markers[item].config.region);
});
mapObject.setSelectedMarkers(selectedMarkers);
mapObject.setSelectedRegions(selectedRegions);
```

Your can remove the whole logic to keep track of the marker index using `last_poi`, which is causing the deselection in `onMarkerOut` and replace with the above function to get the selected `Region` directly from the `mapObject`.